# Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined

Tags: selenium

```
<a href="/lightning/n/******__Country" title="Country" tabindex="0" draggable="false" aria-describedby="operationId-17" class="slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem">
  <span class="slds-truncate">Country</span></a>
```

I got the xpath as

```
WebElement tabName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Country')]"));
```

I need to click the Country link

I have tried the following options but none work

```
 1) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Country') and @title='Country']")).click();

 2)     Actions actions = new Actions((WebDriver) driver.getWebDriver());
                actions.moveToElement(tabName).click().perform();

 3)         ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tabName);
                waitForSeconds(5);
```

I am getting invocation of target exception

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: javascript error: Cannot read
>   property 'defaultView' of undefined

Can any one please tell me how to click the href link?

Comment: Why not linkText with `Country` ?

Comment: What line is the error being thrown on? I'm guessing it's either some install problem where your libraries aren't set up correctly or it's failing on a line you haven't shown us because I don't see why that error would be thrown on any of the lines you have posted.

Comment: It fails when I try to click the element. I have tried the above three ways. Each time I try to click I get that error

Comment: @JeffC I face the same issue, tried with implicit wait, webdriver wait with conditions like element to be clickable but still the issue is same.
The same Salesforce lightning I use too

Answer (score 3):

Try click on its parent/ancestor instead. For example, if you had

```
//a[text()='link of your text']
```

and you get the javascript error, try:

```
//a[text()='link of your text']/parent::*
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code - it works against Salesforce Lightning UI screens:

```
      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath"));
      JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
      executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Sharing it after testing it and found to be working.

Answer (score 2):

To click on the following link use `WebDriverWait` and `elementToBeClickable` and then click on the link using the following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@title='Country']/span[@class='slds-truncate'][contains(.,'Country')]"))).click();
```

Comment: Still the same issue. The error details are as follows:-         Error : javascript error: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-

Comment: is it possible to share url?

Comment: I may not be able to share the URL as I have client restrictions. But its on  SalesForce Lightening platform. Is that fine?

Comment: Is this some SalesForce issue?

Answer (score 0):

For those trying out in python, here is how you do it:

```
>>> button_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="tab-23"]/slot''')
>>> driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button_link )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript. It worked for me

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("strPath"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```